# How do I launch my Spring Batch application after this refactor:

Tags: java, spring-batch

Previously, I had a batch job that used this Cron bean along with the following method to trigger the batch job:

```
public class CronBatchConfig {

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    private Job batchJob;

    @Autowired
    private BatchType batchType;

    private final String ONETIME_BATCH_NAME = "ONETIME";
    private final String RECON_BATCH_NAME = "RECON";

    @Scheduled(cron = "00 00 17 ? * *", zone = "CST")
    public void executeDailyBatch() throws JobParametersInvalidException, JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobRestartException, JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException {

        batchType.setValue(RECON_BATCH_NAME);
        final JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addLong("startTime", System.nanoTime()).toJobParameters();
        final JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(batchJob, jobParameters);
        log.info("Daily batch job status: " + execution.getExitStatus().getExitCode());
    }
```

Now that I have removed the Cronbean class (we are using a different scheduling mechanism) I'm not sure how to trigger this job.
The scheduling mechanism requires no code like the cron bean with the @Schdeuled annoation so Im not sure where to launch the app from.

I tried adding the execute() method to my application class' main method but that is throwing a null pointer :

````
@SpringBootApplication
@Slf4j
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class ReconBatchApplication extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {
    @Autowired
    private static JobLauncher jobLauncher;
    @Autowired
    private static Job batchJob;
    @Autowired
    private static BatchType batchType;
    private static final String RECON_BATCH_NAME = "RECON";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException, JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobParametersInvalidException, JobRestartException {
        ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(ReconBatchApplication.class, args);
        executeDailyBatch();
        System.exit(SpringApplication.exit(context));

    }

    public static void executeDailyBatch() throws JobParametersInvalidException, JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobRestartException, JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException {

        batchType.setValue(RECON_BATCH_NAME);
        final JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addLong("startTime", System.nanoTime()).toJobParameters();
        final JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(batchJob, jobParameters);
        log.info("Daily batch job status: " + execution.getExitStatus().getExitCode());
    }
    ```

Any suggestions would be appreciated
````

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Spring Boot, you can let it launch the job for you, as described in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.batch.running-jobs-on-startup). You only have to define your job as a bean in your application context. Your main method could be something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
   // add job parameters as key/value pairs to args if you want to do it programmatically and not from the command line
   System.exit(SpringApplication.exit(SpringApplication.run(ReconBatchApplication.class, args)));
}
```